# Can you post comments via api to our company's google + site?

Tags: api, post, comments, google-plus

Is there a way that we can use the API to post comments to our company's google + site via the API?  I see you can retrieve comments, but don't see an API method to post comments.

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time based on this [doc](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).  The API to write is still restricted and is only whitelisted to a few Google Partners.